# Disabling Opening of Microsoft Outlook when a single key is pressed

Tags: windows, laptop

I have a HP laptop with windows on it. This keyboard is a UK layout which has various keys  on it , which on pressing different apps. like Microsoft outlook, Calculator, internet browser, Print menu etc...

Every so often i mistakenly press the key which has a mail/envelope symbol on it which opens Microsoft Outlook and it takes ages to open and during that asks for many user confirmations due to not being configured(I don't need it)

How do i disable outlook being opened on pressing of this key?

I remember disabling the Functionality of using F10,F11 without the need to press Fn key with F10,F11 which was also annoying to me.

Answer (score 0):

Check with your drivers, you might have key-mapping software included with them.
If you don't there is a free alternative:
http://code.google.com/p/keymapper/
Essentially this will remap or disable as in your case preferred keys.